# How to plot roc curve for multiclass with scikit-learn?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, roc, multiclass-classification, auc

I am using NSLKDD dataset and i have used Random forest classifier. All of the data is in binary except the class label. I am getting this error with the following piece of code "Can only tuple-index with a MultiIndex"

```
from sklearn.multiclass import OneVsRestClassifier
from scipy import interp
from sklearn.metrics import roc_curve, auc
from itertools import cycle
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.preprocessing import label_binarize


Y = label_binarize(frames, classes=frames.unique())
n_classes = Y.shape[1]
#uniy= frames.unique()
#print(uniy)
#n_classes= uniy.shape[0]
print(n_classes)
X_trainf, X_testf, y_trainf, y_testf = train_test_split(dataforest1,frames,test_size=0.5)
rff=RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators20,max_features='auto',criterion='gini',max_depth=20)

rff.fit ( X_trainf, y_trainf)
y_predf=rff.predict(X_testf)
print(y_predf)
y_score = rff.predict_proba(X_testf)
print(y_score)

fpr = dict()
tpr = dict()
roc_auc = dict()
for i in range(n_classes):
    fpr[i], tpr[i], _ = roc_curve(y_testf[:, i], y_score[:, i])
    roc_auc[i] = auc(fpr[i], tpr[i])
```

[image: Error picture]